# Подскажите, пожалуйста, какое будет сказуемое

Tags: спп, сказуемые

Подскажите пожалуйста, какое будет сказуемое в предложении:

*"Речь должна вырастать и развиваться из знания"?*

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

***Речь должна вытекать и развиваться из знания предмета**. Если же оратор не изучил его, то всякое красноречие является напрасным, ребяческим усилием.*

[Уроки мудрости от Цицерона](https://4brain.ru/blog/%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0/#:%7E:text=%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B8%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F,%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8)

Сказуемое: ***должна вытекать и развиваться.*** Это составное глагольное сказуемое, общая модальная связка "должна" и  основная часть, выраженная  глаголами в форме инфинитивов. Глаголы связаны **однородными отношениями** и союзом И.